# Errors when querying ethereum mempool with python

Tags: web3.py, uniswap, txpool

Im using this script to query the etehreum mempool, but I really dont know exactly what is going on here.

```
from web3.auto import Web3
import asyncio
import json


wss = 'websocket node'
web3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider(wss))

print(web3.isConnected())


uniswapRouter = '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D'
fromAddress = '0x22a26882b4d644ddb7a3e5d21ef4424796fb82db'

def handle_event(event):
    #print(Web3.toJSON(event))
    try:
        getTrans = Web3.toJSON(event).strip('"')
        #print(web3.eth.get_transaction(getTrans))
        trans = web3.eth.get_transaction(getTrans)
        print(trans)
        if trans['to'] == uniswapRouter:
            print(trans)
        else:
            print('nothing')
        
       
   
       

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'error occurred: {e}')



async def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
            handle_event(event)
        await asyncio.sleep(poll_interval)

def main():
   # block_filter = w3.eth.filter('latest')
    tx_filter = web3.eth.filter('pending')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.gather(
                #log_loop(block_filter, 2),
                log_loop(tx_filter, 2)))
    finally:
        loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The first print statement prints out the transaction object as expected, however when I want to print out only transactions going to the uniswapV2 Router, it seems like as if it doesnt print out all the transaction, it prints some but by far not all, because when I check on etherscan I can see that there are many more transactions to the router than what I get in my console.

I also wonder why my except statement kicks in for many transactions.

I have here a sample output from my console

```
nothing
AttributeDict({'blockHash': None, 'blockNumber': None, 'from': '0x9e9cacb85F3745Cb5Cc42D165632Ca2FA0058a94', 'gas': 21000, 'gasPrice': 3000000100, 'hash': HexBytes('0x1b6c6d15c82b674f3e7dc5c8e1a01e6369f1f64b69b3a748c443616118bcda9a'), 'input': '0x', 'nonce': 1, 'to': '0x0Cf96fE7D8DEcBA0B1AfcAAE6e7B82461373989C', 'transactionIndex': None, 'value': 1199530997900000, 'type': '0x0', 'v': 37, 'r': HexBytes('0x754129195a5f29bc039c5ef45bb20d96cb1d97b58efc136b89a11cd3dbd3d3dd'), 's': HexBytes('0x52c8dad2d1a15efd7394ad9c07ffcb8c7b50e5805f6913247deed9d33cbcc9d7')})
nothing
error occurred: Transaction with hash: '0x9c66ccefb900c03996746b3c030dfffe696577c21c66acd6002fcd0b70969cb6' not found.
error occurred: Transaction with hash: '0x5d64b560672674382ee70c1f135145fe125dfc4ba41b08c9d5b0020b56bfdc60' not found.
error occurred: Transaction with hash: '0xfe9cf253def3f0bb04a8d8feed233dd47b21ddfd342325c3e28fbac61a181470' not found.
error occurred: Transaction with hash: '0xfc7397d3f5f092e254aab86bbbce0762fdf2941f5af10822394e9d90bee99c4c' not found.
error occurred: Transaction with hash: '0x8444e145d0ec6dac98116762e0efa0b39678d9a648cc636549a2fdc355eb3335' not found.
error occurred: Transaction with hash: '0x0b434c7dbe9879651f4b00cf1c1ed03e2ab6d344408d852c87d4ce625c37848f' not found.
error occurred: Transaction with hash: '0x378a2acc760d83c3b382afa3924c9b6c2884874317e978ec5dd137c951ebfc17' not found.
error occurred: Transaction with hash: '0x07aff867221c5e17146b47023decad6e6f0566930c3134e5839df20a3bf98a46' not found.
error occurred: Transaction with hash: '0x031f0df8a7dd63591520e9f4d4b4f76aae309a7ec659df8169dbc7bf41db6891' not found.
error occurred: Transaction with hash: '0xcdb9fe4950a8de69f34dc7e759872454f3beb2fbb7a2e23077ca0e50e2da3312' not found.
```

In my script it should print out "nothing" for transaction not going to the uniswap router, which it ocassinally does, but why do i get so many errors?

SO my question is, what is the proper way to query mempool transactions with ethereum and why do I get so many errors.